# trigger oncommand event from page_load event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I am developing site in asp.net and c#.net. I have some 2-3 image buttons on my page. I attached comman oncommand event and command argument for all image buttons for some functionality. My code for oncommand is this

```
protected void btnMenuTab_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  int CID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  MethodToCall(CID);
}
```

This works fine. Now can I call/trigger first image button's click/command event from Page_Load event to call above shown method programmatically. I want instead of user to click button and get result, I on Page_Load programmatically trigger image button click/command event to show result.

Comment: What are you passing in the `CommandArgument`?

Comment: integer value for image button requied for MethodToCall processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for help but I got solution for it. Just call command event method as we call other methods but create parameters for it as per our requirement. see I want to call command event so

```
object mysender = (object)ControNameHere;
CommandEventArgs mye = new CommandEventArgs(null, ControNameHere.CommandArgument);
btn_Command(mysender, mye);
```

Comment: If this resolved your problem please mark it as accepted so that the question is no longer shown as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

You can call:

```
btnMenuTab_Command(btnMenuTab, new CommandEventArgs("commandName", "argument"));
```

But you have to specify the integer you're expecting yourself.